# ASP.Net Core Web API Actions returning anonymous types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.Net Core 5 to create a web API. I use controllers like this

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class User : ControllerBase
{
 ...
 public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUserByID(int id)
 {
    ...
 }
 ...
}
```

This works fine but means I keep creating defined typed classes for the data I am returning. I am interested in returning an anonymous type sometimes rather than a specific type, is this possible?

Comment: No problem at all. But what are you going to do with them after? Maybe you have to select another programming language

Answer (score 4):

You can use `IActionResult`. For example:

```cs
[HttpGet, Route("getUserById/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByID(int id)
{
    var data = await Something.GetUserAsync(id);
    return Ok(new
    {
        thisIsAnonymous = true,
        user = data
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing you "could" do is to return a "string" type all the time by serializing the data - either into a JSON sting or XML. And then interpret accordingly on the client. However, you should ideally look at using the ["ProducesResponseType"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) feature as well as several in-built helper methods to produce different responses based on different conditions - that way you can return different types based on different scenarios. See example below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(User), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(User), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(User), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUserByID(int id)
    {
        try
        {

            User model = await _userService.Get(id);

            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (ApiAccessException apiException)
        {
            ApiFailureDetail detail = new ApiFailureDetail { ApiError = apiException.ApiError, TechnicalMessage = apiException.TechnicalMessage, UserFriendlyMessage = apiException.UserFriendlyMessage };

            //Serialize the exception
            string errorOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detail);

            return Unauthorized(errorOutput);
        }
        catch (ApiException apiException)
        {
            ApiFailureDetail detail = new ApiFailureDetail { ApiError = apiException.ApiError, TechnicalMessage = apiException.TechnicalMessage, UserFriendlyMessage = apiException.UserFriendlyMessage };

            string errorOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detail);

            return BadRequest(errorOutput);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApiFailureDetail detail = new ApiFailureDetail { ApiError = ApiError.InternalError, TechnicalMessage = e.Message, UserFriendlyMessage = "Internal unknown error." };
            string errorOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detail);

            return BadRequest(errorOutput);
        }
    }
```